# Move UIImageView Programmatically

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview

I have a UITableViewCell with 6 evenly spaced images in a row. And when getting my data I dont know if any will be null or how many and if any are `null` I want to shift the other images over to fill in the space left by the empty one. It looks like this

[image]

But then if the first is null I want them all to shift over or if the 3rd is null I want 4,5,6 to move over.

Right now I just check to see what is null with 6 `if` statements and hide if it is discovers a null value. The problem is that I have to check every possible combination of the 6 items being null and where to move them would require a lot and a lot of if statements and then just move them like

```
cell.imageView1.frame = CGRect(x,y, width, height);
```

There must be a better way than a bunch of if statements to check how many and which ones to move. How else can I go about this?

Thanks

Comment: What version of iOS? Can you use a stack view? Also, give them a clear background and use a loop (how are the images stored)

Comment: @Wain I am building for iOS 7 and later currently and I am getting them from database which returns JSON, well call the keys "image1, image2..." so I can arrange the images in away (Array, Dict act) Im just not sure how to efficiently arrange them

Comment: Put the ones you get in a loop and hide unused views

Comment: @Wain I think I get what your saying could you provide a bit of sample

Comment: When you get your data, you know how many of images are null, right? So why don't you draw (or add to view hierarchy) only not-null images then?

Comment: why don't you ask your developer to give you clean data OR ask him to fix the data? that will solve your problem?